# I cannot zoom out in Azure Studio on Mac?

Tags: macos, azure

I am new to Apple and MacOS, and in my Azure program things are too small, or "zoomed out".

To fix this I've tried:

- control option +
- control option -
- control option 8
- control option 0

But none of these worked.

[image]

Comment: If it is not OK to ask where to ask or solve the problem

Comment: First, "MAC" is not "Mac". You're working on a Macintosh (or Apple) computer. "MAC" is an abbreviation for something else. Don't confuse the two and you won't confuse people you're talking to. Second, you're not trying to "zoom out", you're actually already zoomed out, from the screenshot. You need to enlarge the items on the Welcome screen of the Azure application on your Apple computer. This is also called "zooming in". Third, did you look in the View menu? That's normally where you'll see the options to adjust the, you know, view.

Comment: MAC == "media access control" (aka a NIC physical address) ;)

Comment: Mac doesn't use Ctrl for zoom levels, it uses Cmd and 0, - or + [assuming the app supports it]